# Grid with centered numbers

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw a grid in Tikz with centered numbers in each square, from 1901 to 2000. However, I don't know how to properly make the numbers appear in the squares. This is what I wrote:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[very thin, black!30] (0,0) grid (10,10);

        \foreach \y in {9,...,0}
            \foreach \x[evaluate=\x as \z using int( 1900+\x+(10*\y) )] in {1,...,10}
                \node at (\x-0.5,\y+0.5) {\z};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which produces the following. The `evaluate` above isn't working. Could you help me?
[image]

Comment: It is working. You may need to explicitly state the problem you got.

Comment: @CroCo I added a picture showing what appears after I compile. Don't know why it's not working on my computer.

Comment: It's an scope problem, insert second `foreach` inside a pair of `{}` and your code works: `\foreach \y in {9,...,0}{          \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \z using int(1900+\x+(10*\y))] in {1,...,10} \node at (\x-0.5,\y+0.5) {\z};}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `\pgfmathsetmacro` inside the `\foreach` loop instead:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[very thin, black!30] (0,0) grid (10,10);

        \foreach \y in {9,...,0}
            \foreach \x in {1,...,10}
                \pgfmathsetmacro\z{int(1900+\x+(10*\y))}
                \node at (\x-0.5,\y+0.5) {\z};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```